# hibernate inheritance mapping single_table with a property of boolean type

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, nullable, hibernate-annotations

I have this hierarchy for my Entities:

```
TreeItem
LayerItem extends TreeItem
TypicalItem extends TreeItem
```

### TreeItem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tree_item")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name = "item_type",
    discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@DiscriminatorValue("tree_item")
public class TreeItem implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Basic(optional = false)
   private Long id;

   public Long getId() {
     return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
     this.id = id;
   }
   ........
}
```

The inheritance type is `SINGLE_TABLE`.
`LayerItem` has a property `enabled' of boolean type.

### LayerItem:

```
 @Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("layer_item")
public class LayerItem extends TreeItem {

   @Column(nullable = true)
   private boolean enabled = false;

   @Column
   private String position;

   @PrePersist
   public void prePersist() {
       if (JUtil.isEmpty(this.enabled)) //We set default value in case if the value is not set yet.
       {
          this.enabled = false;
       }
   }
}
```

The problem is that when I want to persist a `TypicalItem` (taht does not have the `enabled` property) I face this error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of my.app.entity.LayerItem.enabled
```

I've set a default value (false) for it, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a primitve `boolean` can not be `null`. So you have to change it to a `Boolean` object or make it not nullable:

```
   @Column(nullable = true)
   private Boolean enabled = false;
```

Or

```
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private boolean enabled = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! the first solution solved the problem. The default value (private boolean enabled=false) had no effect.